# vector not in scope c++

Tags: function, vector, struct

I get an error of 'portfolio' is not in scope for 'function.cpp'. I'm trying to call a function with a "vector of structs" passed in the parameters. But i'm assuming i'm not using porfolio correctly. How do get the size of the vector and change the elements inside of the vector? Thank you!

`header.h`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Stocks {
    std::string symbol;
    std::string company;
    int numberOfShares;
    double priceOfShares;
    double totalPrice;
    int time;
};

void sellStock(std::vector<Stocks>& Portfolios, double*);
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<Stocks>portfolio;

int main() {
    sellStock(portfolio);
}
```

`function.cpp`

```
for(int i = 0; i < portfolio.size(); i++) {
    porfolio[i].numberOfShares = portfolio[i].numberOfShares + 1;
}
```

Comment: Where is struct Stocks defined in your main.cpp? above the #include's??

Comment: no its just defined in the header file, but i forgot to include on here, main.cpp does include the header file

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You are passing in an empty portfolio by reference and the for loop will never be entered since size will be 0.